# Create bash script menu with labels

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to create a bash script so I can select a server I can connect to using mosh.
Currently I have this small script that shows me the username and ip of the server.
Its difficult to remember what server does what so I would like to add some remark to the ip.

How could I modify it in such way that it also shows me a label or remark to the menu entry so its easier for me to identify the server.

Currently it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Pick a server (or ctrl-c to quit): '
select item in \
"username@someip" \
"username@someip" \
"username@someip" \
"username@someip" \
"username@someip" \
"username@someip"
do
               mosh $item
exit 0
done
```

which creates the following menu:

```
1) username@someip  3) username@someip  5) username@someip
2) username@someip  4) username@someip  6) username@someip
```

how could I modify this script so it creates the following menu:

```
1) username@someip (some remark) 3) username@someip (some remark)   5) username@someip (some remark)
2) username@someip (some remark) 4) username@someip (some remark)   6) username@someip (some remark)
```

Comment: ?? `"username@someip (some remark)" \ "username@someip (some remark)" \ ` ?

Comment: this will not work because it results in 'mosh username@someip (some remark)'

Comment: Then: do not use select and write your own printing and reading functinality, or filter `(some remark)` from `$item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn (Parameter Expansion Rules)[https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html]

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Pick a server (or ctrl-c to quit): '
select item in "u1@ip1 (foo)" "u1@ip2 (bar)" "u2@ip1 (baz)" "u2@ip2 (foo bar)" 
do mosh "${item%% *}" # strips the unwanted part
done
```